# Getting a build error related to running react-native run-ios

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, visual-studio-code

I am getting this build error when running my react-native run-ios. Anyone have any idea why this happening and how to fix this?

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Check\ Pods\ Manifest.lock /Users/owner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Antiqueruby-hcpclljewzwygrbldgouccnffquk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Antiqueruby.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Antiqueruby.build/Script-FF424E320CA379C0D1F6780E.sh
(1 failure)

Answer (score 5):

Reinstall Pods:

```
rm -rf ios/Pods
bundle exec pod install --project-directory=ios
```